# Keep alive and router-view is not working?

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem with keep alive and router view:

```
<keep-alive>
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view> 
</keep-alive>

routes: [
        {path: '/:id', name: 'detail', component: Detail, props: true },
        {path: '/', name: 'main', component: Main}
      ]
```

I have a component **Detail** contains 2 child components: **Child1** and **Child2**

I have 3 **detail id** when I using router-link on each **detail id**

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id: detailID1}}">
      <a>{{detailID1}}</a>
</router-link>

<router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id: detailID2}}">
      <a>{{detailID2}}</a>
</router-link>

<router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: {id: detailID3}}">
      <a>{{detailID3}}</a>
</router-link>
```

I have problem when I router to **detail 1** every is ok, but when I router to **detail 2** and come back **detail 1** just **Child1** is cached and **Child2** now is from **detail 2** not **detail 1**